# laravel: Undefined property: stdClass::$game

Tags: php, laravel, object

i am trying to get some values out of an Std Object in Laravel.

I can get anything out, with no problem, but not the last one

my object looks like this (var_dump())

```
object(stdClass)[208]
 public 'id' => int 2
 public 'vorname' => string 'Thomas' (length=5)
 public 'nachname' => string 'Kemmet' (length=5)
 public 'geburtstag' => string '1988-05-05' (length=10)
 public 'verein_id' => int 1
 public 'verein_name' => string 'Kolandorf' (length=20)
 public 'game' => string '2016-10-28' (length=10)
```

when i do

```
echo $spieler->id;
```

i get the id. But when i try

```
echo $spieler->game;
```

i get an error with Undefined property: stdClass::$game

why is it like this? and how to get the last value...

Comment: That is odd. So we must assume there is something going on between the creation of the object and where you attempt to echo the property that is effecting the object

Comment: Or is it a scope issue. It would be better if you showed us the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the game field is a string in the database you retrieve it from.
Try changing the order of the fields in order to see if its always the last one which has the problem.